# SSD stalls my Windows 2003 installation

Tags: ssd

I've just installed Windows 2003 Server on a Corsair CMFSSD-64N1 64GB SSD and I am quite baffled from the outcome... This is the slowest experience I've ever had with my computer. When running a single program (ie: chrome) everything works fine. But the moment I start 3-4 applications my system starts to stall. I can't even scroll a web page in chrome for 2-10 seconds... During installations computer becomes almost unusable. I've never experienced something like this before. Any thoughts or ideas?

thnx

Comment: see also: http://superuser.com/questions/60155/ssd-stalls-my-windows-installation

Comment: answered on SU - http://superuser.com/questions/60155/ssd-stalls-my-windows-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well known issue with this type of SSD.